# inserting array in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Currently I have an Array that looks like the following when output thru print_r();

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi Viswa Mahavidyalaya

| Kanchipuram, Chennai
[1] =>
Karpaga Vinayaga College of Engineering and Technology

| Kanchipuram, Chennai
[2] =>
SRM University, Chennai - Kattankulathur Campus

| Kattankulathur, Chennai
[3] =>
Saveetha University, Thandalam

| Thandalam, Chennai
[4] =>
B.S. Abdur Rahman Crescent University

| Vandalur, Chennai
[5] =>
P.B. College of Engineering

| Sriperumbudur, Chennai
[6] =>
Saveetha Engineering College

| Thandalam, Chennai
[7] =>
Hindustan University

| Kelambakkam, Chennai
```

I would like to insert this data into one table with each element value belonging to its respective field.

actually m scraping data from a website.i hv used some regex.all the array fetched contains 30 values each.all the arrays contains desired result but m nt able to figure out how to insert them into database.even your method is also nt working for me
for loop used is:

```
for ($i=0;$i<30;$i++)
{   $temp1 = $names[1][$i];
    $temp2 = $location[2][$i];
    $temp3 = $facilities[1][$i];
    $temp4 = $reviews[1][$i];





    $sql = 'INSERT INTO collegedb (Name,Location,Facilities,Reviews) VALUES ("$temp1","$temp2","$temp3","$temp4")';
$run=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql);}
```

Can someone help me understand how I should approach this situation? 
here is a link to full code http://paste.ubuntu.com/24422534/

Comment: Variables won't work as you want in single quotes. Parameterizing the query will be safer/more reliable.

Comment: can you tell how?

Comment: How do you expect to extract facilities and reviews when your data doesn't contain any facilities or reviews?

Comment: How to parameterize? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: actually there are three more arrays containing facilities,reviews and location.

Comment: None of these solutions are going to work then, because you didn't provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

@Clearshot66 answer fits well with your question so this is extra: If you ever consider moving to PDO which is much better than mysqli may this helps you:

```
    $req = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO document (nom,date_creation,prix,auteur) VALUES (:nom, :date_creation, :prix
    , :auteur)');
    $req->execute(array('nom' => $document->getNom(), 'date_creation' => $document->getDateCreation()
    , 'prix' => $document->getPrix(), 'auteur' => $document->getAuteur()));
```

Simple example of inserting an object of class Document in database secured. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people are telling you to use PDO when you're clearly using mysqli

The formatting of your data is a disaster, so I'll just make up some sample data we can work with

```
$data = [
  'names' => ['first', 'second', 'third'],
  'locations' => ['Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Shanghai'],
  'facilities' => [1, 4, 9],
  'reviews' => ['good', 'best', 'average']
]
```

The goal will to be to insert data into our table like this

```
name      location   facility   review
--------------------------------------
first     Berlin     1          good
second    Tokyo      4          best
third     Shanghai   9          average
```

At the basis of our query, we will be using [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which is intended to be used to (safely) inject variant data into a query

[`mysqli_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) allows you to inject integers, doubles, strings, and binary blobs. In the examples below, we will be injecting strings `s` and integers `i`

```
// basic example
$city = 'Reykjavik';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select district from cities where city=?')
$stmt->bind_param('s', $city);
$stmt->execute();
```

In your case, we have an array of data tho, so we need to execute our query multiple times. Luckily, we can prepare a statement once, and bind/execute multiple times. A simple loop will do the trick

```
// make the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('insert into collegedb (Name, Location, Facilities, Reviews) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

// run it once for each set of values
for ($i=0; $i < count(data['names']); $i++) {
  $name = $data['names'][$i];
  $loc = $data['locations'][$i];
  $fac = $data['facilities'][$i];
  $rev = $data['reviews'][$i];
  $stmt->bind_param('ssis', $name, $loc, $fac, $rev);
  $stmt->execute();
}

// close the statement
$stmt->close();
```

---

**Using `array_map` makes this easier**

If you have a recent version of PHP, you can make this solution a lot nicer using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and a splat argument.

```
// make the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('insert into collegedb (Name, Location, Facilities, Reviews) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

// map over data
array_map(function($name, $loc, $fac, $rev) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ssis', $name, $loc, $fac, $rev);
  $stmt->execute();
}, ...array_values($data))

// close the statement
$stmt->close();
```

---

**Even less hand-holding**

The previous method using `array_map` is fine, but disguised within the code is a 2d array transposition. Instead, we could write a generic transpose function, then first transpose your data, then loop over it. It will result in less cognitive load overall

```
$entries = [
  ['first', 'Berlin', 1, 'good'],
  ['second', 'Tokyo', 4, 'best'],
  ['third', 'Shanghai', 9, 'average']
];
```

We can derive `$entries` from `$data` using our handy `array_transpose` function. Then looping over the data and executing our statement becomes a lot easier

```
// reusable transpose function
function array_transpose($xs) {
  return array_map(null, ...array_values($xs));
}

// derive entry data
$entries = array_transpose($data);

// make the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('insert into collegedb (Name, Location, Facilities, Reviews) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

// run it once for each entry
foreach ($entries as $values) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ssis', ...$values);
  $stmt->execute();
}

// close the statement
$stmt->close();
```